# Post name parameter-passing issue in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parameter-passing, auto-populate

I'm building a job listing page and job application form in my website using WordPress, Elementor, Contact Form 7 and ACF, I have created custom post type named career and add cutom fields for this custom pot type.

Also I have created template for the job pages using elementor theme builder, this template is meant to be used for any job that will be posted to the site.

The template has apply button at the end of the job page, where I need this button to pass the job title (custom field) to the application form page so I have set the link to be as following: "https://mywebsite.com/application_page/?page_title_value=page_title"

Then I have written JS code to get the parameter value from the link and to place it in the field which is as following:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var pageTitleValue = urlParams.get('page_title_value');
        if (pageTitleValue) {
            document.querySelector('#form-field-field_06ac371').value = pageTitleValue;
        }
    });
</script>
```

What happens is that the field is auto populated with the following "page_title" not the value it self, I'm having issue with passing the page title or post title from the job page to the application form page, hopefully someone could help on solving this.